# Skype thru SSH tunnel not working

Tags: macos, networking, ssh, proxy, skype

At school, many ports but 21, 25, 80 and the ones for IMAP and POP3 are closed by a firewall, preventing students to go into "malicious" places. Obviously, this has turned into an issue. As it evolves, I need to contact somebody via skype frequently for some class related things - They are in hospital, and due to other influences, i must be able to use skype over the school's network, without killing my iPhone's 3G volume.

To get HTTPS working, I used a SSH tunnel:

```
ssh -D 8888 -p 25 xxx@xxx.xx
```

The first trick was to use the non-blocked and non-influenced by the cache SMPT port. My server has five outgoing IPs, so it was rather easy to throw one away for this kind of hack, since all my websites run on a single ip anyway, leaving the others for testing and alike.

Secondly, I used `-D` to generate a SOCKS proxy. In Mac OS X, my host OS, I specified that in the Settings -> Network place.

But when I launch skype, it just stays blank. No online users or whatsoever. If i use `ssh -v (...)` to watch the things happen, I see that skype attempts to do something, but fails.

I was thinking a bit about why this wouldn't work and came up with those questions:

- Do raw TCP/UDP connections actually work over SOCKS?
- Is there a difference in transmitting SSL supported requests via the native gateway or thru a SOCKS proxy?
- Is there a way to make Skype work, at all?

Comment: Don't forget Skype uses ports 80 and 443. Open Skype as I believe there is a tick box to get it to not use this... I forget the setting detail but it relates to ports. You may be c able to configure a different port. It seems Skype can't connect to the external service but it can log in... confusing as it should use 443 to authenticate as well as transmit the call data...

Comment: @BigChris There is no option for that on the OS X version - I have never seen one there.

Comment: When  you connect through your tunnel can you get to the Internet (through browser) and test HTTP and HTTPS pages work? I.e. tunnel all your traffic over your SSH tunnel

Comment: @BigChris Yes, that works just as expected. Basically, everything BUT Skype works...